# Send notification to UWP app from remote server without cloud support

Tags: windows, uwp, wns

How can I notify a UWP app from remote server? Is it possible with Windows notification service, I don't want implement with cloud service. Is there any possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That's absolutely possible. The server-side component can be any cloud hosted service or it can be your own custom implementation and hosted somewhere on your on-prem servers. 
You can create a simple service using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh868252(v=win.10) and host that on your remote server.

Comment: Windows notification service Is possible with side loaded app? Is Developer account  needed for same?

Comment: Yes. That's one of the Prerequisites. For more details see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh465407

Comment: However, this works on Side loaded builds as well. You just need an app created on Windows Developer Dashboard. Once you have the ClientSecret and Package security Identifier then you can use on a sideloaded app as well. Mark my Answer as answer if I answer your question.